# Angular navigation as href

Tags: angular, navigation, href

When click an button, I want my angular component to be rendered in whole browser instead of rendering with appcomponent

I have tried routerlink, navigate to as well as lazy loading. I can't get as I wanted

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: Click edit button and add your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.